# What security issues are there with creating a daemon that reads internet-facing sockets?

Tags: c++, c, security, sockets, daemon

I have a personal server which uses Pushover to communicate with me. That is, my server can trigger a script that sends a message straight to my phone, with varying priority. This is, however, one way. I hope to get around this by using Pushover's ability to add a html link.

I know socket code very well, but I'm somewhat hazy on security involved therein. An example of how this would work is that the power goes out. My server is on a UPS, and as such instantly send me a message on my phone saying that the power is out, do I want the system to shut down? (subsequent messages may be sent on power restoration, meaning I may not wish for it to shut down.) It would include a link to, say example.com:4000/insert_a_generated_hash_here.
If I decided that I did want the server to shut down, the daemon watching port 4000 would receive

```
GET /insert_a_generated_hash_here HTTP/1.1\r\n
host: www.example.com\r\n
\r\n
```

The first thing I'm worried about is a non-null terminated strings. How much of an issue is that? Would recv automatically null terminate?

Regardless, I take the http get and hash it (or should I not- how safe is hashing a potentially hostile string?).

The http get would hash to 25b382b678bb33a21fa677c66e9d02a1 if I used MD5 (Should I use MD5? It's just the first hash I thought of).

At this point, that hash (which should be safe to manipulate?) is compared to a table of 'currently active' commands. Since the server made the original generated hash, it can make a hash of an http request. If the incoming hash matches something in the table, that command is run- pre-canned commands only, of course. Commands are also only active for 10 minutes, at which point they are removed from the active list. I may also add a 'non-active' list, which sends me a message on my phone saying "This command was issued, but it was not active."

In this case, the command would have been a shutdown, though it may be approval for a user on the server to install something through a package manager, etc etc. The daemon may also send back the relevant http response for a simple web page just saying "OK!" (I don't think that would be a big deal?)

How secure is this, and what things should I watch for? Or is the entire idea the pinnacle of security suicide?

Comment: Please correctly tag this with the language you're asking about. Otherwise, your question is almost incomprehensible. For example, you ask about "non-null terminated strings", but "string" means something completely different in C (an array of characters that is nul terminated) from what it means in C++ (a class in the library).

Comment: Sorry- I plan on writing this in C++, as I'm the most familiar with it, but all socket code is, by necessity, in C.

Comment: Umm, I've written tons of socket code in C++.

Comment: Maybe I'm being pedantic, but socket code itself is in C. You can just call it in a C++ program, but they still use standard C types like character arrays of null terminated strings, etc. That is what I meant.

Comment: Socket code can be written in C or C++. The very same code can be C or C++, just as "Jose" can be English or Spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5, although widely used, is known to be [broken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). Look into SHA-1 or something similar instead.

You should never assume anything null-terminates (or that it provides correct null-termination at all as DavidSchwartz said below). If your application depends on this, make sure to do it yourself on the daemon upon receiving requests. Indeed this is important; you don't want to have a buffer overflow by happily reading or manipulating a "string" which doesn't terminate and simply trashes your memory.

When you say "table" are you referring to a lookup table hardcoded within the daemon, or a database table? If these things are happening within memory, you should be ok since they are not "executable." For instance, if you are using a database, a malicious user may be able to craft an attack string which exploits your database in some way (either exposing all contained data or gaining unauthorized access to the system). Hashing a malicious string should have no effect, however, if you are not adding any salts to the hash, it may be possible for a malicious user to hash his string himself and execute the command if you allow commands to be directly executed on your system (sorry, I am not sure you have given a full view of your system).

In any event, your strategy (whenever it is feasible and maintainable) is good from a security standpoint. Explicitly enumerating exactly what can be run gives you more complete control over how your system will act. This is a form of user input sanitation; you take a raw user request and translate it (or not if it's invalid) to work properly within your system. That said, if any of these requests use the raw user input, you may want to do further checking. That is, if the request is not simply translated (i.e. you receive `shutdown <message>`) it is important to sanitize `<message>` before simply executing it (it could be malicious code). If this is not the case (i.e. you just receive `shutdown` and perform the proper action), then I would not worry.

As far as sending a web-response, this is probably OK. If the response is hardcoded (and not grabbed from a dynamic source), I would not worry about this so much. The hardcoded response will be safe since it is not trying to read anything else from disk and this sending cannot be exploited (assuming no buffer overflows, etc.).

Another attack-vector I could think of is if there is no authentication. If this is an open-server, you may want to lock it down some how for a sort of admission control. This will prevent malicious users from executing completely valid commands on your server in an unauthorized way.

**EDIT**

To secure the web interface more, I would recommend using even just a simple user-authentication form. Relying simply on the hashes follows the [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) principle and this should not be relied on. Notice that this form suffers from the same user input issues as discussed before (input sanitation, buffer overflow, etc.). It may be simplest to hash the user input directly in some encoded way (i.e. `sha1(user:pass)`) and compare this hash to a list of valid login hashes which must be stored somewhere. This helps with user input sanitation since `sha1(malicious_payload)` will be a simply hash. That said, this still does not protect from buffer overflows which you must be actively checking for. In general, use length-specified versions of commands like `strncpy` or `strncmp` instead of `strcpy` and `strcmp`. Finally, this form may still suffer from social engineering attacks (i.e. password phishing) and password stealing if your password leaks in someway. That said, these are not failures in the system, but often in the human component of security.

Comment: If you just never assume anything nul terminates, you fall victim to problems if someone does maliciously send you a string that contains an unexpected nul. You must ensure your system is secure both if you never assume anything nul terminates and if you assume everything nul terminates. Assume any possible combination of bytes might be sent to you.

Comment: There will be no raw user input. The lookup table will be hardcoded into the daemon, but external programs may be able to ask the daemon to flag a command as active. The response would be hardcoded. What kind of authentication should I be using, if not the generated hash with timeout, that would work via an html link followed via a mobile browser?

Comment: @user52544: The generated hashes should be fine but I would not rely on [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). Perhaps, when visiting these pages, you create a simple web user authentication page before executing a command. Force the visiting user to login in someway (i.e. through a POST form or similar). This, of course, has the same vulnerabilities as it does in any web interface, however. Those include brute-force, password stealing/phishing, etc.

Comment: Hmm. So it would be security through obscurity to require a time-sensitive hash that is randomly generated each time? (e.g. two  shutdown commands that are identical are going to have separate hashes.) if that is the case, it's going to add significant complexity to sanitize the POST request.

Comment: @user52544: Security through obscurity relies on a system being secure only due to the malicious adversary not knowing part of the system; security should be approached with the mindset that you have an all-knowing malicious adversary. I have updated my post to include some more information. Two shutdown commands can be identical if you properly account for this case, however, the user login should be the same page served up anytime anyone tries to execute one of those commands. If the user cannot identify (say, 3 or 5 attempts?) then invalidate the command.

Comment: Hmm. So if I'm going to be adding a login form regardless, should I bother with randomly generated hashes? Or just have it check for, example.com/shutdown, and then login? I'll probably still have the time kill for the command, though. The reason I ask is because in pushover, you have a maxiumum message limit, and a lengthy hash in the link would result in a significantly shorter message being sent.

Comment: @user52544: This is a design-decision. Using a hash may make it less-likely an adversary (unless they are very persistent to gain access) can effectively brute-force the login (they first need to find a login page). But, again, no provable amount of security is necessarily removed from the system in not hashing.

Comment: Oh, wait, hang on- I think there may be a miscommunication here. let's say an event happens, and the url is example.com/g3 (greatly simplified) for the shutdown. After 10 minutes, that expires. The next time we have an event, even for another power failure, it will not be g3- it's another randomly generated code that only lasts 10 minutes. This is going to be open sourced, preferably- they can know all they want about the system, but they need that randomly generated hash within 10 minutes after it's made, and I don't even know what that is outside the pushover message.

Comment: Or would even that still be considered security through obscurity? (sorry, ran out of room.) As you can tell, I'm fairly new at this.

Comment: @user52544: I understand - but, although unlikely, it is possible for an attacker to somehow obtain that address (SMS-sniffing - unlikely, but possible). So I would not recommend relying on this. If the programming is too much for now, it is a design-decision, but from a security standpoint this should not be relied on.

Comment: It's not actually through SMS, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's more secure. I understand though. I guess my final question is this- how would I prevent the authentication page my daemon sent from resulting in the daemon receiving the POST request with the user name and password in plaintext? (eek!)

Comment: @user52544: You could hash it on the client-side (javascript or something else) before sending it - that said, this leaves the system vulnerable if they obtain your login hash; they could directly send the correct hash. The other way would be to use SSL - there are a few libraries which already have SSL implemented for `C++` (i.e. `boost` or `POCO`).